# which soap method should i use to link php and wsdl?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

im so new to this and been trying to understand the way to link this whole thing together..my ultimate target is to apply a c program on a hard coded webpage. e.g. i hard code a variable to "age", once i load php it suppose to print out "30", if i put it to "name", it prints "jack"

first step should be generate soap files and wsdl  file right? so i use gsoap to compile and i have got the wsdl file which it has this location "  ".....and the function name "getAnswer" is also in there

now how should i call this function and print the answer out...what should be the next step i should do? its been confusing me a lot

Comment: So you used [gSOAP (the C++ Toolkit)](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) to make the SOAP server and  you need help creating a SOAP client and web interface in PHP?

Comment: yup..ive made some progress and now its outputing Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest\server\t.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest\server\t.php(9): SoapClient->__call('getMobile', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest\server\t.php(9): SoapClient->getMobile(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest\server\t.php on line 9

Comment: Glad to know you are making progress. Looks like you are using the built-in SoapClient class - good choice. If you have a more specific question you could either edit this one (hate to have a question go to waste) or start a new one.

Comment: thanks, i just put a new question for my new issue. linking php and soap took me almost a week and thats all i could figure out. any good tutorial to recommend? btw here is the link for new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911716/fatal-error-uncaught-soapfault-exception-client-looks-like-we-got-no-xml-doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using the built-in SoapClient Class.

There are several resources / how-tos / guides on-line. Here are a few:

[Coding Friends - PHP - Soap Client calling .NET Web service](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/04/16/soap-client-calling-net-web-service/)

[Patrick's Playground - Simple PHP SOAP example](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/)

[php.net - SoapClient Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Comment: I've rechecked again and the format are 100% matched..the address thing you mentioned might be important.how do i check the connection? what i know is that it should be connected now

Comment: If your SoapClient runs on a Linux server, you can do a ping and traceroute in the shell. If you are in windows you can try a ping or even try to pull it up in a browser. ... The thing is that the wsdl is normally located close to the SOAP "server."