# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in

Tags: php, soap

i used gSOAP (the C++ Toolkit) to make the SOAP server and i suppose to use php send a getMobile request to soap client and print a resultant phone number

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("test.wsdl",array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>true, 'user' => 'Grace' ));
$arrParameters_Login = array('user' => 'Grace');
//$arrParameters_Login = array('complexType' => (array('sequence' => (array('user' => 'Grace')))));  
$objLogin =  $client->getMobile($arrParameters_Login); 
die;
?>
```

error when i load php file with xampp on browser

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document  
in C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest\server\t.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest
\server\t.php(9): SoapClient->__call('getMobile', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\soaptest
\server\t.php(9): SoapClient->getMobile(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs
\soaptest\server\t.php on line 9
```

I've searched around for so long but couldnt find a way to solve my problem..any idea? is it something to do with my wsdl file? or location?

```
<service name="test">
 <documentation>gSOAP 2.8.3 generated service definition</documentation>
 <port name="test" binding="tns:test">
  <SOAP:address location="http://192.168.82.52:8080"/>
 </port>
</service>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire wsdl or provide a link to it? Also, are you sure that the php code can connect to the server which is located at http://192.168.82.52:8080?